# When does a C# Task actually start?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

When does a Task actually start?

```
public void DoSomething() {
    Task myTask = DoSomethingAsync();

    Task.WaitAll(new[] { myTask }, 2000);
}

public async Task DoSomethingAsync() {
    await SomethingElse();
}
```

Does it start immediately when initializing it in `Task myTask = DoSomethingAsync();` or does it start when you say to wait for it in `Task.WaitAll(new[] { myTask }, 2000);` ?

Comment: This is a big question. Have a look here for starters: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: Patrick Hofman already has given the correct answer. For your example: `DoSomethingAsync()` will immediatly run as far as  possible - which means e.g. up to the first point where it awaits some inner task inside which has not yet finished. Only then it will return and the continuation will get attached. If `DoSomethingAsync()` has dozens of nested await functions inside, where all complete synchronously (e.g. the last one is a `Task.FromResult()`) then `myTask` will be completed before the control is given back to the caller.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Calling an `async` method returns a *hot* task, a task that has already been started. So there is no actual code necessary to force it to run.

According MSDN ([thanks to Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089372/when-does-a-c-sharp-task-actually-start/43089445#comment73270562_43089445)) the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) pattern [requires returned tasks to be hot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4). That means that all tasks, except those created with `new Task` will be hot.

From the referenced article:

> Tasks that are created by the public `Task` constructors are referred to as cold tasks... All other tasks begin their life cycle in a hot state.

Comment: "When you call a method that returns a Task without async, it will not be started." sounds a bit confusing to me. Majority of methods that return task without async still return task that is already started, because they start it inside method itself.

Comment: @Evk 'automatically' > better?

Comment: The `async` modifier is used by the compiler to build the state machine. Other than the constructors of `Task`/`Task<T>`, any API I can think of returns an hot task. That's what `Task.Run` does. So, what do you mean by "When you call a method that returns a `Task` without `async`, it will not be started automatically."?

Comment: `return new Task ...` for example @PauloMorgado

Answer (score 0):

I would like to contribute with some examples even though Patrick Hofman gave the answer (especially by pointing to this section in the linked article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap?redirectedfrom=MSDN#task-status).

Hopefully the examples can help with the interpretation.

If you start by just making some simple HOT tasks you would see they start as soon as they have been initialised.

```
// Using just some HOT task
var first = Task.Delay(2_500);
var second = Task.Delay(2_500);

await Task.Delay(2_500);

Console.WriteLine("Start awaiting HOT tasks");
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
await Task.WhenAll(first, second);
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

The above code snippet will output below which validates that the tasks has been running between the initialisation and `await Task.WhenAll(…)`.

```
Start awaiting HOT tasks
00:00:00.0000866
```

Now if you instead used the Task constructor the task wouldn’t be started but be in state `TaskStatus.Created`. We need to start them explicitly as in below example:

```
// Using Task constructor
var firstNew = new Task(() => Task.Delay(2_500).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
var secondNew = new Task(() => Task.Delay(2_500).GetAwaiter().GetResult());

await Task.Delay(2_500);

Debug.Assert(firstNew.Status == TaskStatus.Created && secondNew.Status == TaskStatus.Created);
firstNew.Start();
secondNew.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Start awaiting NEW tasks");
stopwatch.Restart();
await Task.WhenAll(firstNew, secondNew);
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

above code gives output:

```
Start awaiting NEW tasks
00:00:02.5070535
```

If you would use either `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory` they would return started task. As a example this code:

```
// Run
var firstRun = Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(2_500));
var secondRun = Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(2_500));

await Task.Delay(2_500);

Console.WriteLine("Start awaiting RUN tasks");
stopwatch.Restart();
await Task.WhenAll(firstRun, secondRun);
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);

// Factory 
var firstFactory = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await Task.Delay(2_500));
var secondFactory = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await Task.Delay(2_500));

await Task.Delay(2_500);

Console.WriteLine("Start awaiting FACTORY tasks");
stopwatch.Restart();
await Task.WhenAll(firstFactory, secondFactory);
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

outputs:

```
Start awaiting RUN tasks
00:00:00.0002207
Start awaiting FACTORY tasks
00:00:00.0005118
```