# Best way to add delay to each message received?

Tags: c#, tcp, latency

I have a client-server architecture and I am sending messages from the client to the server every 70ms. On the server side, I want to introduce a simulated network latency. To do this, I have the following:

```
//Receive incoming messages and put into temp queue.
private void DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    TemporaryRawMessages.Enqueue(args.Bytes);
    args.Recycle();
}

//Runs on separate thread
void ProcessMessages()
{
    while (true)
    {

        if (TemporaryRawMessages.Count > 0)
        {
            var raw = TemporaryRawMessages.Dequeue();
            Task taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DelayedReceive(raw));
        }

    }
}

//Process the received message
void DelayedReceive(byte[] raw_message)
{
    //wait a bit before deserialising and queueing the message
    while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < LatencyUp) { }
    var message = (ClientToServerMessage)Utils.Deserialize(raw_message);
    Messages_In.Enqueue(message);

}
```

The server receives a message and puts it into a temporary queue.
Next, `ProcessMessages()` picks up any new messages and spawns a new Task. The task waits a bit before putting the message into another queue, which is picked up by the main program.

The problem is that if I time DelayedReceive, I see timings such as: 3, 241, 46, 99,... There is no consistency. Each message should be delayed by 70ms, offset by the network latency up. In other words, all messages are delayed by X (eg 100ms), but are equally spaced apart at 70ms.

Any ideas on what the issue is?

Comment: Why can't you just use Thread.Sleep?

Comment: If your work is synchronous, then `Thread.Sleep(70)`, if asynchronous then `await Task.Delay(70)`. Right now you are doing fire and forget with `Task.Factory.StartNew`. If this is for tests then I would remove that and simply use `Thread.Sleep(70)`

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new `Task` there is no guarantee that it will be started right away, it is just a promise that the code will be executed at some point in time.

Meaning, that your `DelayedReceive` method will be called at some point in time. But it does not have to be right away.

The timings can be explained as you are referencing an external variables (`sw` and `LatencyUp`) inside the `DelayedReceive` method. Multiple tasks can reference these values in *presumably* the wrong order.

See also:

- [When does a C# Task actually start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089372/when-does-a-c-sharp-task-actually-start)
- [Task vs Thread differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429129/task-vs-thread-differences)

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the clarification. I had assumed that the task would be started immediately.

Comment: But if you await `Task.Run`, then it will be scheduled with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` instantly, so the difference might be around ~10ms