# Execute Task in new background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I know there are a million questions on this and I am trying their solutions but it does not seem to behave as I would expect.

With the following code:

```
await Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); Console.WriteLine("I'm running after Thread.Sleep"); });
Console.WriteLine("I'm running after Task.Run");
```

I get the output:

```
[ 5 seconds elapses ]
I'm running after Thread.Sleep
I'm running after Task.Run
```

Which is the same output I would get without using `Task.Run`

What I want is the output:

```
I'm running after Task.Run
[ 5 seconds elapses ]
I'm running after Thread.Sleep
```

Where execution of the 'parent' thread continues and the long-running task is executed 'in the background' in a way which does not affect the 'parent' thread.

Comment: You need to remove the await keyword from the task.run, because you are awaiting the execution of the Task.Run in order to continue the execution of your program

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned you need to remove the `await`. **However** that turns it into a *fire-and-forget* task which, if the above code just happens to be in say a console app's `Main` then your process could terminate before the task has completed.

**Good:**

```
 // C# 7
 static async void Main(string[] args) // <--- note `async` signature
 {
     await Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); Console.WriteLine("I'm running 
                 after Thread.Sleep"); });
     Console.WriteLine("I'm running after Task.Run");
 }
```

**Bad:** - fire-and-forget task that isn't `await`ed

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); Console.WriteLine("Spider Man: I don't wan't to go!"); });  // POOF!! 

     Console.WriteLine("I'm running after Task.Run");

     // sorry Spidy, you're dead
 }
```

So you might not see `I'm running after Thread.Sleep` at all even if you have a `Thread.Sleep()`. (by the way you should be using `Task.Delay()`).  You could mitigate it with a `Console.ReadKey()` but that might defeat the purpose.

Fire-and-forget tasks have their uses, and can be used reasonably safely in other types of **long-running** apps like say WinForms but people generally don't go spawning Tasks in the process's entry point so the tasks generally run to completion without any early termination by the process.  However, it's generally a good idea to use `await` where you can so you don't shoot yourself in the foot.

Also, your requirements of wanting things in a certain order sort of demonstrates a misunderstanding of how `async/await` works.

Comment: `Task.Run` threw me off, because I've always known that you have to `await` or `Wait()` a `Task` returned by a method, otherwise nothing will happen. However `Task.Run` is an exception to that rule: It returns a `Task` the lambda function runs without doing `await Task.Run`

Comment: @Frayt _"otherwise nothing will happen"_ - incorrect.  Calling an `async` method returns a [hot task, a task that has already been started](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43089445/585968).  By adding `await` you ensure that the `Task` gets a chance to run to completion before the next line in the code is executed.  `Task.Run()` being a _"method"_ also [returns a hot task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43089445/585968).   Use `Wait()` as a last resort.  If you are calling an `async` method from a method that can itself be changed to `async`, you can avoid the `Wait()`.  `Wait` defeats the purpose

Answer (score 5):

One thing to keep in mind when working with `await` is that your code awaits *objects*. These objects are just like any other objects. Specifically, they can be assigned to local variables or class variables.

So, this code:

```
await Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); Console.WriteLine("I'm running after Thread.Sleep"); });
Console.WriteLine("I'm running after Task.Run");
```

is essentially the same as this code:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); Console.WriteLine("I'm running after Thread.Sleep"); });
await task;
Console.WriteLine("I'm running after Task.Run");
```

In other words:

1. Start a task running on a background thread.
2. Asynchronously wait (`await`) for that task to complete.
3. Display `"I'm running after Task.Run"`.

So the output is expected.

> What I want is the output:
>
> I'm running after Task.Run
>
> [ 5 seconds elapses ]
>
> I'm running after Thread.Sleep

In that case, start the task running on the background thread, but don't `await` it until later:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); Console.WriteLine("I'm running after Thread.Sleep"); });
Console.WriteLine("I'm running after Task.Run");
await task;
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to run asynchronously you should remove the command away

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " => I'm running after Thread.Sleep"); });
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " => I'm running after Task.Run");
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
```

Output

`28/05/2019 09:49:58 => I'm running after Task.Run
28/05/2019 09:50:03 => I'm running after Thread.Sleep`