# How to bundle async tasks for Task.WhenAll?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I fire up some async tasks in parallel like the following example:

```
var BooksTask = _client.GetBooks(clientId);
var ExtrasTask = _client.GetBooksExtras(clientId);
var InvoicesTask = _client.GetBooksInvoice(clientId);
var ReceiptsTask = _client.GetBooksRecceipts(clientId);

await Task.WhenAll(
    BooksTask,
    ExtrasTask,
    InvoicesTask,
    ReceiptsTask
);

model.Books = BooksTask.Result; 
model.Extras = ExtrasTask.Result; 
model.Invoices = InvoicesTask.Result; 
model.Receipts = ReceiptsTask.Result;
```

This results in a lot of typing. I searched the .Net Framework for a way to shorten this up. I imagine it to be lile this. I call the class `Collector` as I don't know how to name the concept.

```
var collector = new Collector();

collector.Bind(_client.GetBooks(clientId), out model.Books);

collector.Bind(_client.GetBooksExtras(clientId), out model.Extras);

collector.Bind(_client.GetBooksInvoice(clientId), out model.Invoices);

collector.Bind(_client.GetBooksRecceipts(clientId), out model.Receipts);

collector.Run();
```

Is this a valid approach? Is there something like that?

Comment: Can these tasks truly run in parallel?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Just imagine the `Get()` calls of the client going to a database or a remote procedure call.

Comment: I am imagining exactly that and for example if you use EF, it does not support that kind of thing anyway.

Comment: [Correct approach to wait for multiple async methods to complete](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19285/correct-approach-to-wait-for-multiple-async-methods-to-complete)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I prefer the code in the question (but using `await` instead of `Result` for code maintainability reasons). As noted in [andyb952's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57108505/263693), the `Task.WhenAll` is not required. I do prefer it for readability reasons; it makes the semantics explicit and IMO makes the code easier to read.

> I searched the .Net Framework for a way to shorten this up.

There isn't anything built-in, nor (to my knowledge) any libraries for this. I've thought about writing one using tuples. For your code, it would look like this:

```
public static class TaskHelpers
{
    public static async Task<(T1, T2, T3, T4)> WhenAll<T1, T2, T3, T4>(Task<T1> task1, Task<T2> task2, Task<T3> task3, Task<T4> task4)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3, task4).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return (await task1, await task2, await task3, await task4);
    }
}
```

With this helper in place, your original code simplifies to:

```
(model.Books, model.Extras, model.Invoices, model.Receipts) = await TaskHelpers.WhenAll(
    _client.GetBooks(clientId),
    _client.GetBooksExtras(clientId),
    _client.GetBooksInvoice(clientId),
    _client.GetBooksRecceipts(clientId)
);
```

But is it really more readable? So far, I have not been convinced enough to make this into a library.

Answer (score 3):

In this case I believe that the WhenAll is kind of irrelevant as you are using the results immediately after. Changing to this will have the same effect.

```
var BooksTask = _client.GetBooks(clientId);
var ExtrasTask = _client.GetBooksExtras(clientId);
var InvoicesTask = _client.GetBooksInvoice(clientId);
var ReceiptsTask = _client.GetBooksRecceipts(clientId);

model.Books = await BooksTask; 
model.Extras = await ExtrasTask; 
model.Invoices = await InvoicesTask; 
model.Receipts = await ReceiptsTask;
```

The awaits will take care of ensuring you don't move past the 4 later assignments until the tasks are all completed

Comment: It's relevant, it would allow the tasks to execute in parallel technically.

Comment: Yes, but they would still run in parallel in code above, the WhenAll is an unneccessary call.

Comment: So, it what scenarios would I use `Task.WhenAll()` then?

Comment: The error handling is slightly different - if you use Task.WhenAll, then it will await them all, even if one of them fails early

Comment: @aggsol you should use `Task.WhenAll` when you have a list of homogeneous tasks, and want to get the results as an array.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out in [andyb952's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57108395/how-to-bundle-async-tasks-for-task-whenall#57108505), in this case it's not really needed to call `Task.WhenAll` since [all the tasks are *hot and running*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089372/when-does-a-c-sharp-task-actually-start).

But, there are situations where you may still desire to have an `AsyncCollector` type.

---

TL;DR:

- `Async` helper function [usage example](https://gist.github.com/tommasobertoni/9b189408d4872a85cfa1b5e5751effdd)

```cs
async Task Async(Func<Task> asyncDelegate) =>
    await asyncDelegate().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

- `AsyncCollector` [implementation](https://gist.github.com/tommasobertoni/14a20c684c897c6f06f4bbc76d5da064), [usage example](https://gist.github.com/tommasobertoni/cdb967b6c0154b67c87a37300736e1c8)

```cs
var collector = new AsyncCollector();

collector.Register(async () => model.Books = await _client.GetBooks(clientId));
collector.Register(async () => model.Extras = await _client.GetBooksExtras(clientId));
collector.Register(async () => model.Invoices = await _client.GetBooksInvoice(clientId));
collector.Register(async () => model.Receipts = await _client.GetBooksReceipts(clientId));

await collector.WhenAll();
```

If you're worried about closures, see the note at the end.

---

**Let's see *why* someone would want that.**

This is the solution that runs the tasks concurrently:

```cs
var task1 = _client.GetFooAsync();
var task2 = _client.GetBarAsync();

// Both tasks are running.

var v1 = await task1;
var v2 = await task2;

// It doesn't matter if task2 completed before task1:
// at this point both tasks completed and they ran concurrently.
```

**The problem**

*What about when you don't know how many tasks you'll use?*

In this scenario, you can't define the task variables at compile time.
Storing the tasks in a collection, alone, won't solve the problem, since the result of each task was meant to be assigned to a specific variable!

```cs
var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

foreach (var translation in translations)
{
    var translationTask = _client.TranslateAsync(translation.Eng);
    tasks.Add(translationTask);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

// Now there are N completed tasks, each with a value that
// should be associated to the translation instance that
// was used to generate the async operation.
```

---

**Solutions**

A workaround would be to assign the values based on the *index* of the task, which of course *only works if the tasks were created (and stored) in the same order of the items:*

```cs
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Count; i++)
    translations[i].Value = await tasks[i];
```

A more appropriate solution would be to use `Linq` and generate **a `Task` that identifies two operations: the fetch of the data and the assignment to its receiver**

```cs
List<Task> translationTasks = translations
    .Select(async t => t.Value = await _client.TranslateAsync(t.Eng))
    // Enumerating the result of the Select forces the tasks to be created.
    .ToList();

await Task.WhenAll(translationTasks);

// Now all the translations have been fetched and assigned to the right property.
```

This looks ok, until you need to execute the same pattern on another list, or another single value, then you start to have many `List<Task>` and `Task` inside your function that you need to manage:

```cs
var translationTasks = translations
    .Select(async t => t.Value = await _client.TranslateAsync(t.Eng))
    .ToList();

var fooTasks = foos
    .Select(async f => f.Value = await _client.GetFooAsync(f.Id))
    .ToList();

var bar = ...;
var barTask = _client.GetBarAsync(bar.Id);

// Now all tasks are running concurrently, some are also assigning the value
// to the right property, but now the "await" part is a bit more cumbersome.

bar.Value = await barTask;
await Task.WhenAll(translationTasks);
await Task.WhenAll(fooTasks);
```

---

**A cleaner solution** *(imho)*

In this situations, I like to use **a helper function that wraps an async operation** (any kind of operation), very similar to how the tasks are created with `Select` above:

```cs
async Task Async(Func<Task> asyncDelegate) =>
    await asyncDelegate().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Using this function in the previous scenario results in this code:

```cs
var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var t in translations)
{
    // The fetch of the value and its assignment are wrapped by the Task.
    var fetchAndAssignTask = Async(async t =>
    {
        t.Value = await _client.TranslateAsync(t.Eng);
    });

    tasks.Add(fetchAndAssignTask);
}

foreach (var f in foos)
    // Short syntax
    tasks.Add(Async(async f => f.Value = await _client.GetFooAsync(f.Id)));

// It works even without enumerables!
var bar = ...;
tasks.Add(Async(async () => bar.Value = await _client.GetBarAsync(bar.Id)));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

// Now all the values have been fetched and assigned to their receiver.
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/tommasobertoni/9b189408d4872a85cfa1b5e5751effdd) you can find a full example of using this helper function, which without the comments becomes:

```cs
var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var t in translations)
    tasks.Add(Async(async t => t.Value = await _client.TranslateAsync(t.Eng)));

foreach (var f in foos)
    tasks.Add(Async(async f => f.Value = await _client.GetFooAsync(f.Id)));

tasks.Add(Async(async () => bar.Value = await _client.GetBarAsync(bar.Id)));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

---

**The AsyncCollector type**

This technique can be easily wrapped inside a "`Collector`" type:

```cs
class AsyncCollector
{
    private readonly List<Task> _tasks = new List<Task>();

    public void Register(Func<Task> asyncDelegate) => _tasks.Add(asyncDelegate());

    public Task WhenAll() => Task.WhenAll(_tasks);
}
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/tommasobertoni/14a20c684c897c6f06f4bbc76d5da064) a full implementation and [here](https://gist.github.com/tommasobertoni/cdb967b6c0154b67c87a37300736e1c8) an usage example.

**Note:** as pointed out in the comments, there are risks involved when using closures and enumerators, but [from C# 5 onwards the use of `foreach` is safe](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/) because closures will close over a fresh copy of the variable each time.

It you still would like to use this type with a previous version of C# and need the safety during closure, the `Register` method can be changed in order to accept a *subject* that will be used inside the delegate, avoiding closures.

```cs
public void Register<TSubject>(TSubject subject, Func<TSubject, Task> asyncDelegate)
{
    var task = asyncDelegate(subject);
    _tasks.Add(task);
}
```

The code then becomes:

```cs
var collector = new AsyncCollector();
foreach (var translation in translations)
    // Register translation as a subject, and use it inside the delegate as "t".
    collector.Register(translation,
        async t => t.Value = await _client.TranslateAsync(t.Eng));

foreach (var foo in foos)
    collector.Register(foo, async f.Value = await _client.GetFooAsync(f.Id));

collector.Register(bar, async b => b.Value = await _client.GetBarAsync(bar.Id));
await collector.WhenAll();
```

Comment: This is different and last I check somewhat dangerous,  You should not be assigning models properties in a closure when you didn't have to

Comment: can you elaborate on the dangers of this use case? This implementation seems like a fit for the desired experience of having to fetch multiple independent data asynchronously, and then assigning the values to different fields / properties

Comment: There are a few issues with doing this, I don't remember them all but I know when you can avoid it you should.  Closing over the variable is just one issue you can read about it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/) P.S I wasn't the person who downvoted you I'm just giving you additional information

Comment: As you can see at the beginning of the article that you linked:
*In C# 5, the loop variable of a foreach will be logically inside the loop, and therefore closures will close over a fresh copy of the variable each time.*
Therefore, closures over `foreach` in c# >= 5 are _safe_.

Comment: No it means that there is inconsistencies between versions and it just one example of why it's not a recommended practice especially when it could be avoided, to go on to state that it's safe is a fallacy

Comment: I added support for delegates that don't require closure.

Comment: @johnny "You should avoid doing this but I don't remember why" is not a good argument. Unless of course you have reached the status of Jon Skeet or Eric Lippert, in which case even vague memories qualify as good arguments. 

Comment: Don't misquote me, like you misquoted the article.  " I don't remember them all but... Closing over the variable is just one issue"  1.   Closures lead to bugs when capturing variables in properly.   2. As you mentioned there are inconsistencies between versions.  3. There are more issues with closures.   That should be good enough reasons to make assignments inside your funcs.

Comment: I don't think something that _can_ be dangerous should _never_ been used: i.e. you can always use a temp variable inside the loop if you really want to own the safety measures.

Comment: My proposed solution does work and solves the problem with a look & feel like the one described in the answer. With the help of your suggestions @johnny5, the current solution is even better and safer than the first one that I posted, but I'm aware that this implementation is opinionated. It's not that I recommend to use this technique, but I did used it and worked fine, and to me it seemed it resembled what the question asked.