# Start 3 Tasks exactly at the same time milliseconds precision

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, task

in my WPF App i have 3 tasks which i would like to start all at the same time at t=0.
When a Start button is pressed the function Start_Click() is executed which starts the three tasks and writes the start moment of the tasks to the trace window when the tasks are done.
It appears that at the most 7 msec of time differs between the start moment of the tasks and most of the time this occurs only the first time the Start button is pressed. After that pressing the Start button repeatedly the start moments of the tasks are much more the same.
How can this be explained and improved? This is a simplified version of the application in which this problem occurs.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(10, 10);
    }

    private async Task<DateTime> TaskDelay(CancellationToken cancellationToken, double delayTimeMSec)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(delayTimeMSec));
        return now;
    }

    private async void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var taskArray = new List<Task<DateTime>>()
        {
            TaskDelay(cts.Token, 1000), TaskDelay(cts.Token, 2000), TaskDelay(cts.Token, 4000)
        };
        
        await Task.WhenAll(taskArray);

        foreach(var task in taskArray) 
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"{task.Result.Minute}:{task.Result.Second}:{task.Result.Millisecond}");
        }
    }
}
```

**19:48:664**
19:48:671
19:48:671
The thread 0x4ea8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

19:57:272
19:57:272
19:57:272

20:3:446
20:3:446
20:3:446

20:9:325
20:9:325
20:9:326

20:14:967
20:14:967
20:14:967
The thread 0x4be8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

20:20:519
20:20:520
20:20:520

20:25:904
20:25:904
20:25:904

20:31:237
20:31:238
20:31:238

20:36:503
20:36:503
20:36:503

Comment: Is this just out of curiosity or does your app _actually_ depend on 3 Tasks starting at the exact same instant?

Comment: Not necessarily the most efficient solution, but one idea which comes to mind is passing the same `DateTime startAfter` parameter to your tasks (This could be calculated a few ms after the current time of `Start_Click`. You can then wait inside the task body itself until this time, which may give you more fine control?

Comment: I would say the three values are taken sync, cause your _now_ variable is written before the first await call.

Comment: That is not it i'm afraid. I checked the duration of the tasks and they also tend to be inaccurate the first time the Start button is pressed. There is something about the first time the Tasks are started.

Comment: My app does actually depend on starting 3 Tasks at the same time, posted here is just a simplified version to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you really intend to do? There is no threading going on in the example. So you example is essentially just calling `DateTime.Now` three times in succession, and then starting a timer to print each value after a delay. It could be written much simpler and with less overhead. Also, the concept of "at the same time" does not really exist at the lower levels of a CPU, the best you can do is  tell if something happened before or after some synchronized event.

Comment: That is right, i'm trying to start 3 tasks at the same time and control the delay accurately. What i discovered was that its only inaccurate the first time the tasks are started, after that it becomes more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It appears that at the most 7 msec of time differs between the start moment of the tasks

You are initializing the tasks, and starting their execution sequentially:

```
var taskArray = new List<Task<DateTime>>()
{
    TaskDelay(cts.Token, 1000), 
    TaskDelay(cts.Token, 2000), 
    TaskDelay(cts.Token, 4000)
};
```

Without seeing the implementation of `TaskDelay()` its hard to be specific, but that method is likely returning a *"Hot"* task ([described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43089445/1690217)) that has already been started. The method itself will run *synchronously* until the first `await` or a task is deliberately returned.

The first time this method runs, the *"cold"* start, the memory allocations and state engines will be setup and cached, this takes a small fraction, but measurable amount of time.

> After that pressing the Start button repeatedly the start moments of the tasks are much more the same. How can this be explained

On subsequent calls, the previously compiled logic can be executed from the cache and is expected to be much faster, there should still be some delay, but it will be significantly faster.

> How can this be improved

How much of a problem is it really? 7ms is still a pretty tight tolerance in many situations, the physical mouse button press itself will take longer than that.

If the cold start time is not acceptable to you then one "cheat" way to solve this is to simply start some tasks and discard them, however this will require you task to not have any external affects, or you should pass through a parameter so that it doesn't mutate anything outside the method call.

Alternatively you could deliberately create *"cold"* tasks via `TasK()` constructors as described in [Task Class on Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-7.0)

```
// Create a task but do not start it.
Task t1 = new Task(action, "alpha");
```

- You would do this inside the `TaskDelay()` method.

However you will still need to iterate through the tasks to run them, `Task.WhenAll()` will not *start* the tasks, it only waits for their completion. So this means there is always *some* delay between the tasks starting, even if it is often negligible.

- In this case most of the initial cold start time would be spent in creating the tasks, so it might be the only trick you need.

You can try to use [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) but this still has both a synchronous procedural initialization sequence and the starting of the tasks can sometime be even more unpredictable.

I would strongly recommend you review the requirement, even if you use scheduling to try and achieve precise parallel and concurrent execution, your solution will still be prone to failure or delays caused by other environmental factors.

Even in industrial processing there are delays when you want precision, the trick is to minimise the delay but also to make the system more robust so that it is not affected by delays. Think about when you verbally instruct to people to complete a task, but to start when I say "GO". There will be factors that lead to their reaction times being different as well as their operating speeds and efficiencies, even though we issued a single command. Similar issues occur in your program.

Comment: *"Without seeing the implementation of `TaskDelay()`"* -- It is included inside the question.

Comment: *"returning a "Hot" task"* / *"the "cold" start"* -- You are using the terms hot and cold for two completely unrelated phenomena, which makes your answer confusing and misleading. Most people perceive hot as the opposite of cold, and given this reasonable assumption your answer makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added private variables for each Task to create 'cold' tasks in the constructor of MainWindow(). The start moment of the tasks is much better. I understand the reason for the delay better.